# Extreme values in pgfplot curve

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am trying to produce this graph (produced with Wolfram Alpha):

[image]

This is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots,tikz}

\begin{document}

\newcommand\erfinv[1]{(0.5*sqrt(pi))*(#1 + (pi/12)*#1^3 + (7*pi^2/480)*#1^5 + (127*pi^3/40320)*#1^7 + (4369*pi^4/5806080)*#1^9 + (34807*pi^5/182476800)*#1^11)} 

\begin{figure}[t]
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
        axis x line=bottom,
        axis y line=left,
        smooth,
        ytick=\empty,
        %ymax=10,
        xtick={0,1},
        xmin=0,
        xmax=1.15]
        \addplot[thick,domain=0.0:0.99,samples=500] {exp(0+0.25*sqrt(2)*\erfinv{2*x-1})};
        \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}   
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The output is this:

[image]

I reckon the problem is due to extreme values and number of points. But using a finer method like the one below does not improve the output:

```
\addplot[thick,domain=0.0:0.05,samples=5000] {exp(0+0.25*sqrt(2)*\erfinv{2*x-1})};
\addplot[thick,domain=0.05:0.95,samples=50] {exp(0+0.25*sqrt(2)*\erfinv{2*x-1})};
\addplot[thick,domain=0.95:1,samples=5000] {exp(0+0.25*sqrt(2)*\erfinv{2*x-1})};
```

Is there a way to solve this? Maybe another way to plot it? Maybe create the data manually? Matlab?

Comment: Use `declare function={erfinv(\x) = (0.5*sqrt(pi))*(\x + (pi/12)*(\x)^3 + (7*pi^2/480)*(\x)^5 + (127*pi^3/40320)*(\x)^7 + (4369*pi^4/5806080)*(\x)^9 + (34807*pi^5/182476800)*(\x)^11) ;}` in your tikzpicture as an option to define a function but are you sure that your expansion is correct ?

Comment: You have at least two errors in your function. The first one is that in the definition of `\erfinv` you have to surround `#1` by parentheses. Otherwise, after replacing the parameter by `2*x-1` expressions like `#1^5` will read `2*x-1^5`, probably not what you want. There is at least a second error, since your function has value 0 for x=0, whereas Wolfram's graph has a value bigger than zero. This doesn't seem to be a rounding error. What is erf?

Comment: erf is the error function. TO me the wolfram code is correct. Its just a problem of approximation too. The free version of wolfram stops at a certain time of computation.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not using y axis notation, but the crossing point is not 0. I use declare function, but still cannot capture all concavity. I took the series from [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=series+expansion+at+x%3D0+of+erfinv(x)). The suggested (#1) effectively corrects the graph, but does not improve the fit much.

Comment: You are almost certainly better off to create an external file with the data. I don't think you have enough precision in `pgf` to calculate $erf^{-1}(x)$ correctly near -1.

Comment: @Derek Yes, sometimes forcing latex too far is not appropriate. Added solution using `pgfplotstable`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many attempts, I took Derek's advice and went for externally generated data. The final code is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable,tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[t]
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    axis x line=bottom,
    axis y line=left,
    ytick=\empty,
    ymin=0,
    xtick={0,1},
    xmin=0,
    xmax=1.15]
    \pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{my_data.txt}\mytab;
    \addplot[smooth,thick,mark=none] table [y=Y, x=X]{\mytab};
    \addplot+[mark=none,dashed,gray,thick] coordinates {(1, 0) (1, 2.2)};               
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}   
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

which gives me a nice graph!

[image]

For reference, I created the data with Matlab, as follows:

```
x = [0:0.001:1]';
y = exp(0+0.25*sqrt(2)*erfinv(2*x-1));
T = [x,y];
dlmwrite('my_data.txt',T, ',')
```

Comment: Looks great! Good solution.

Answer (score 2):

The function `\erfinv` needs to be rewritten, that intermediate results does not vanish the number range, supported by `fpu`,used by `pgfplots`. Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots,tikz}

\begin{document}

\newcommand*{\erfinv}[1]{%
  (((((34807/89100 * pi * (#1)/2 * (#1)/2
  + 4369/11340) * pi * (#1)/2 * (#1)/2
  + 127/315) * pi * (#1)/2 * (#1)/2
  + 7/15) * pi * (#1)/2 * (#1)/2
  + 2/3) * pi * (#1)/2 * (#1)/2
  + 2) * (#1)/2
  * sqrt(pi)/2
}

\begin{figure}[t]
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
        axis x line=bottom,
        axis y line=left,
        smooth,
        xmin=0,
        xmax=1.15]
        \addplot[thick,domain=0:1,samples=100]
          {exp(0.25 * sqrt(2) * \erfinv{2*x-1})};
        \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}   
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Sorry, I don't get how this solves the question. The graph is virtually the same.